# VB.NET: Unknown KeyDown Event Issue

Tags: c++, vb.net, controller, arduino, keydown

**EDIT:FINAL SOLUTION:**

Seeing as the final solution was buried in comments, I'll put it here for future viewers.

My problem is that the signal I was using to stop an action included "r", also the command for stop (I thought I was being clever, combining my "left" command and "stop" command). The C++ (arduino) code read each caharacter individually, hence stopping the signal altogether, not just the one which I wanted.

Thankyou to **dbasnett** for poitning this out :)

Alrighty, hi all, this is my final question for this latest project of mine. The idea, simply, was to make a program to control an RC car through an arduino. It works!!! (with only a small bug).

Simply, I use the arrow keys or WASD to control the program. It sends a signal through a Serial Port to the arduino, which has a few functions in it for interpreting the signal. You have a total of 9 signal that can be sent; one for each direction, one to stop each directional input (e.g. left makes car point wheels left, stop-left points the wheels straight ahead).

The PROBLEM IS: When I go both FORWARD (or reverse) and LEFT (or right), if I change DIRECTION (left/right), it stops all together. I've spent most of the project trying to work this out, and I just can't see what Im doing wrong.

so, my code:

```
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Shared _continue As Boolean
    Shared _serialPort As SerialPort
    Shared lturn As Boolean
    Shared rturn As Boolean
    Shared keydelay As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        SerialPort1.PortName = "com3" 'change com port to match your Arduino port
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = 115200
        SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
        SerialPort1.Parity = Parity.None
        SerialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One
        SerialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None
        SerialPort1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default 'very important!

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown

        Dim bHandled As Boolean = False

        If SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
        Else
            SerialPort1.Open()
        End If

        Select Case e.KeyCode

            Case Keys.Right

                pbBgML.BackColor = Color.Transparent
                pbBgMR.BackColor = Color.Black
                SerialPort1.Write("d")

                e.Handled = True

            Case Keys.Left

                pbBgMR.BackColor = Color.Transparent
                pbBgML.BackColor = Color.Black
                SerialPort1.Write("a")

                e.Handled = True

            Case Keys.Up

                pbBgBC.BackColor = Color.Transparent
                pbBgTC.BackColor = Color.Black
                SerialPort1.Write("w")

                e.Handled = True

            Case Keys.Down

                pbBgTC.BackColor = Color.Transparent
                pbBgBC.BackColor = Color.Black
                SerialPort1.Write("s")

                e.Handled = True

            Case Keys.Space

                SerialPort1.Write("r")

                e.Handled = True

        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp

        Select Case e.KeyCode

            Case Keys.Right
                pbBgMR.BackColor = Color.Transparent
                SerialPort1.Write("dr")

            Case Keys.Left
                pbBgML.BackColor = Color.Transparent
                SerialPort1.Write("ar")

            Case Keys.Up
                pbBgTC.BackColor = Color.Transparent
                SerialPort1.Write("wr")

            Case Keys.Down
                pbBgBC.BackColor = Color.Transparent
                SerialPort1.Write("sr")

        End Select

    End Sub

End Class
```

Also, if you want it, the arduino code (in C++):

```
    // Car Control v. 0.2

int reversePin = 9;
int forwardPin = 8;
int leftPin = 10;
int rightPin = 11;

byte byteRead;
int time;

void forward(int time){
  digitalWrite(reversePin, HIGH);
  Serial.println("This is forward...");
  digitalWrite(forwardPin, LOW);
  delay(time);
}

void reverse(int time){
  digitalWrite(forwardPin, HIGH);
  Serial.println("This is reverse...");
  digitalWrite(reversePin, LOW);
  delay(time);
}

void left(int time){
  digitalWrite(rightPin, HIGH);
  Serial.println("This is left...");
  digitalWrite(leftPin, LOW);
  delay(time);
}

void right(int time){
  digitalWrite(leftPin, HIGH);
  Serial.println("This is right...");
  digitalWrite(rightPin, LOW);
  delay(time);
}

void off(){
  Serial.println("This is stop...");
  digitalWrite(leftPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rightPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(reversePin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(forwardPin, HIGH);
}

void setup() {
  // initialize the digital pins as an output.
  pinMode(rightPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(leftPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(forwardPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(reversePin, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("\n\nStart...\n");
}

void loop() 
{
  //Turn everything off...
  if (Serial.available()) {
    /* read the most recent byte */
    byteRead = Serial.read();

    switch(byteRead)
   {
     case 'w':
     forward(5);
     break;

     case 'wr':
     digitalWrite(forwardPin, HIGH);
     break;

     case 's':
     reverse(5);
     break;

     case 'sr':
     digitalWrite(reversePin, HIGH);
     break;

     case 'a':
     left(5);
     break;

     case 'ar':
     digitalWrite(leftPin, HIGH);
     break;

     case 'd':
     right(5);
     break;   

     case 'dr':
     digitalWrite(rightPin, HIGH);
     break;

     case 'r':
     off();
     break;

    }
  }
}
```

Sorry for the huge blocks of text, but I simply have no idea where the issue is. Cheers guys.

Comment: It could be because some of the commands are two characters and some are one.  Try making the commands one character each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help with the C code but the VB code could use a single byte for the control

```
<FlagsAttribute()> _
Enum ctrl As Byte
    stp = 0 'stop is no bits set
    frwd = 1 << 0 '1
    back = 1 << 1 '2
    left = 1 << 2 '4
    rght = 1 << 3 '8
    mask = 255
End Enum

Private _control(0) As ctrl

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Right
            _control(0) = _control(0) Or ctrl.rght
        Case Keys.Left
            _control(0) = _control(0) Or ctrl.left
        Case Keys.Up
            _control(0) = _control(0) Or ctrl.frwd
        Case Keys.Down
            _control(0) = _control(0) Or ctrl.back
    End Select
    'SerialPort1.Write(_control, 0, 1)
    Debug.WriteLine(_control(0))
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Right
            _control(0) = _control(0) And (ctrl.mask Xor ctrl.rght)
        Case Keys.Left
            _control(0) = _control(0) And (ctrl.mask Xor ctrl.left)
        Case Keys.Up
            _control(0) = _control(0) And (ctrl.mask Xor ctrl.frwd)
        Case Keys.Down
            _control(0) = _control(0) And (ctrl.mask Xor ctrl.back)
    End Select
    'SerialPort1.Write(_control, 0, 1)
    Debug.WriteLine(_control(0))
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not understanding this code real well; what is actually being sent through the Serial Port?

Comment: One byte with certain bit(s) on / off.  You will need C++ code to decode one byte.

Comment: I haven't the faintest idea how to do that, which is why I was sending characters, which are really easy to throw straight into a case statement.....

Comment: I imagine you can find code to test individual bits in C here.  If you want send characters then change your code to send ONE character for each command, instead of two for some commands.  The problem is that you are assuming that when you issue the read that you will always have the appropriate amount of characters.

Comment: When you issue the read in C are you assuming that you will read two chars if two are sent?  In relative terms a long time passes between each character arrival.  So if you send two the C code may read one, process it, and then read the next and process it, instead of reading two and processing them both.  That is why I am suggesting that you make your commands one character.

Comment: ahhhh, I get it. Ill try it, and report back

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is a little off here.

I would suggest that you use a bit field to determine which input is being pressed with a different bit for each input (as each one is effectively independent).

```
Private _input As Integer = 0

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    'set the bit of the required input
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Right
            _input = SetBit(_input, 0) '0001
        Case Keys.Left
            _input = SetBit(_input, 1) '0010
        Case Keys.Up
            _input = SetBit(_input, 2) '0100
        Case Keys.Down
            _input = SetBit(_input, 3) '1000
    End Select
    SerialPort1.Write(Convert.ToChar(_input))
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    'clear the bit of the de-selected input
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Right
            _input = ClearBit(_input, 0)
        Case Keys.Left
            _input = ClearBit(_input, 1)
        Case Keys.Up
            _input = ClearBit(_input, 2)
        Case Keys.Down
            _input = ClearBit(_input, 3)
    End Select
    SerialPort1.Write(Convert.ToChar(_input))
End Sub

Private Function SetBit(value As Integer, bit As Integer) As Integer
    ' Create a bitmask with the 2 to the nth power bit set:
    Dim mask As Integer = CInt(2 ^ bit)
    ' Set the nth Bit:
    value = value Or mask
    Return value
End Function

Private Function ClearBit(value As Integer, bit As Integer) As Integer
    ' Create a bitmask with the 2 to the nth power bit set:
    Dim mask As Integer = CInt(2 ^ bit)
    ' Clear the nth Bit:
    value = value And Not mask
    Return value
End Function
```

You then need to do the opposite in the C++ code (which should be much more elegant) and check for invalid key combinations (e.g. forward and backward together)

Ideally you would want to pass a Byte to the serial port no a character, but I have tried to keep it as similar as possible

Comment: how would I interpret the bitfield in C++??? My knowledge of VB isn't fantastic, but I'd never even touched C++ before this project....

Comment: Have a look at the Wikipedia page (with examples in C!): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field Give it a try and if you get stuck, post a new question on that part

Comment: The basic approach is sound.  The implementation is dependent upon converting an Integer to a Char.  Take a look at what I posted for other ideas of how sending one byte can be accomplished.

Comment: @dbasnett - I tried to keep the example as similar to that posted (it is already sending chars) to reduce the amount of code changes on the C++ side.

Comment: @MattWilko I'd have to look at Convert.ToChar(_input) to know what character is being sent based on the bit values and encoding inherent in the Convert.  I'll bet the OP can find some C++ code to detect bits being on / off in a byte.  I suspect the problem was what I commented on in the original post.

Comment: tried putting this in a vb project, but I added a line in the KEYUP function to show me what is being written to serial in a MsgBox, but it gives me nothing. Code was: MsgBox(Convert.ToChar(_input)), directly asfter the SerialPort.Write line.

Comment: The `character` is not human readable because it is something like `Chr(1)` but your C code will be able to read it. Try showing the numeric value instead: `MsgBox(_input)`

Comment: still nothing. and yes guys, i know i could probably find a piece of code to interpret it on the other end, but I really dont understand c++, the simpler I keep that, the easier it is on me.

Comment: Im still convinced there is a logic issue I haven't thought of yet, in terms of shutting off the forward/backward motion....I've defintitely seen a page about this specific issue (another site), but cant find it ....